# Use 2 tables from different connections for running join query using airflow Dag

Tags: python, oracle, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have `table1` and `table2` from Oracle. `table1` belongs to `db1` and `table2` with `db2`.

I have to perform a join between these two tables. Shared `extract_sql` demo query in the comment for reference.

I tried to pass connections through the list:

The function to extract from the database looks like this:

```
ORACLE_CONN_ID1 = 'c1'
ORACLE_CONN_ID2 ='c2'

def extract_from_oracle(extract_sql):
    logger.info('extract_sql: '+str(extract_sql))
    try:
        oracle_conn_id = [ORACLE_CONN_ID1, ORACLE_CONN_ID2]
        con=0
        while con in oracle_conn_id:
            oracle_hook = OracleHook(con)          
            conn = oracle_hook.get_conn()
            #conn = oracle_hook.get_conn()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            with open(extract_sql, 'r') as f:
                sql = f.read()
            cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: ------SQL file:-----

'select su.login as "USER_NAME",
          su.FIRST_NAME,
          su.SYSTEM_USER_STATUS as ACCOUNT_STATUS,
          su.HIRE_DATE as ACCOUNT_CREATED_DATE
   from db2.system_user su
     left join db1.s_user x ON (su.login = x.user_name)
   where su.system_user_status = 'enabled'
    AND x.user_passwd not like '%_DISABLED'
    AND x.app_userid = 0
   group by su.login,
            su.FIRST_NAME,
            su.LAST_NAME 
   order by su.login'

Comment: You cannot join two tables outside the cursor, because a database doesn't know anything about "other" connections. You may create a database link in one of the databases and perform join here with `... from schema.table join other_schema.other_table@dblink ...`. Or extract required information from one database and pass it as parameters to the statement for the other database.

Comment: Don't add comments to clarify, code is hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead.